# How to wrap a shared pointer of a template class function in Pybind11

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11, template-classes

I want to wrap a shared pointer of a template class function in Pybind11.
My class is a template queue :  **MyQueue.hpp**

```
template<typename Data>
class MyQueue {
    public:
        std::queue <Data> the_queue;
        static std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<Data>> make_data_q_ptr();
};
```

**MyQueue.cpp**

```
template<typename Data>
std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<Data>> MyQueue<Data>::make_data_q_ptr(){
    std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<Data>> data_q_ptr;
    data_q_ptr = std::make_shared<MyQueue<Data>>();
    return data_q_ptr;
}
```

The type of data in MyQueue :
**DataType.cpp**

```
class DataType
{
    public:
        uint mynumber;
};
```

The wrapper using Pybind11 :
**wrap.cpp**

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m){
    
    py::class_<MyQueue<DataType>, std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<DataType>>>(m, "MyQueue_DataType")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def_static("make_data_q_ptr",&MyQueue<DataType>::make_data_q_ptr);
            
    py::class_<DataType>(m, "DataType")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def_readwrite("mynumber",&DataType::mynumber);
}
```

**Command to compile the code**

```
g++ -shared -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lpthread -std=c++11 -I./pybind11/include/ `python3.7 -m pybind11 --includes` *.cpp -o mymodule.so `python3.7-config --ldflags`
```

The code gets compiled successfully, but when I try to import the module that I created "mymodule", I get this error: **ImportError:  undefined symbol: xxx**

```
>>> import mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/pi/templedpybind11/mymodule.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7MyQueueI8DataTypeE15make_data_q_ptrEv
```

Can you please help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
template<typename Data>
std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<Data>> MyQueue<Data>::make_data_q_ptr(){
    std::shared_ptr<MyQueue<Data>> data_q_ptr;
    data_q_ptr = std::make_shared<MyQueue<Data>>();
    return data_q_ptr;
}
```

into your header file.  It isn't visible at the point that needs to see it.